# how to list data order by date in mvc view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, datatables

Iam using mvc, i want to retreive data in index view order by date.

```
var cn = from a in db.table1 
         join b in db.table2 on a.Country equals b.CountryCode
         join c in db.table3 on a.DealerId equals b.CompID  
         order by a.date desc select a;

return View(cn.ToList());
```

without datatables it is working fine, but datatables not allowing to sort by date. it is only displaying the data by primary key value order
Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Just to clarify, are you using .net mvc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
            $('#id').dataTable( {
                "aaSorting": [[ 2, "desc" ]]  //2 - number of column
            } );
        } );
```

if you dont want to display the date column through which you are sorting 
then use

```
"aaSorting": [[12, "desc"]],
        "aoColumnDefs": [{ "bVisible": false, "aTargets": [12] }],
```

upto this level it will sort only columns which are in datatable
so u need to use linq query

```
return view(cn.OrderByDescending.ToList());
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use linq orderby, for example:

```
.OrderByDescending(x => x.Date);
```

Comment: There is no problem with linq query, datatable making the issue

Comment: I needed this simple addition to my linq to get what I wanted which was photos sorted by date taken desc. Thanks. . . . . . var photos = db.Photos.OrderByDescending(x => x.TakenOn).ToList();

Answer (score 0):

Look at [this](http://datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/basic_init/table_sorting.html)
example of usage. 
 Set "aaSorting" attribute to sort by date.

```
     $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#youTableId').dataTable( {
                "aaSorting": [[ 2, "desc" ]]  //2 - number of column
            } );
        } );
```